# Union Bound of two events?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds, empirical-processes

> I am trying to understand the assumption proof of Theorem 2(Page -$7$) in the paper ["A Universal Law of Robustness via isoperimetry"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.12806.pdf) by Bubeck and Sellke.

**Inequality 1**

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E}[f]\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon^{2} n d}{9^{4} c L^{2}}\right)
\end{align}

Since we assumed that the range of the functions is in $[-1,1]$ we have $\mathbb{E}[f] \in[-1,1]$ and hence:

**Inequality 2**

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}[f] z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}\right| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right)
$$

**By Hoeffding's inequality, the above quantity is smaller than $2 \exp \left(-n \epsilon^{2} / 8^{3}\right)$ (recall that $\left.\left|z_{i}\right| \leq 2\right)$.**

Thus we obtain with an union bound:

**Inequality 3**

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i}\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{4}\right) & \leq|\mathcal{F}| \cdot \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E}[f]\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}\right| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \\
& \leq 2|\mathcal{F}| \cdot \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon^{2} n d}{9^{4} c L^{2}}\right)+2 \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

I am not getting how Union bound is getting happened using Ineq 1 and 2. Can anyone help me with that how they able to reach last inequality?

Comment: In your inequality 3, can you clarify what the $f$ inside the first probability after the inequality is referring to? Does the inequality hold for every $f$ or one specific $f$? I'm asking because the left hand side does not depend on a specific $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there are three events $E_{7}$,$E_{8}$ and $E_{9}$ such as $E_{7} := \underbrace{\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E}[f]\right) z_{i}}_{A} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{8}$

and $E_{8} := \underbrace{\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}[f] z_{i}}_{B} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{8}$

and $E_{9} := \underbrace{\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i}\right) z_{i}}_{C}\leq \frac{\epsilon}{4}$

For simplicity I can write

\begin{align}
A - \frac{\epsilon}{8} \leq 0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
B - \frac{\epsilon}{8} \leq 0
\end{align}

Adding Eq $19$ and $20$

\begin{align}
    A + B \leq \frac{\epsilon}{4} 
\end{align}

which is $C \leq \frac{\epsilon}{4} $

Hence,
$$
\mathbb{P}(E_{7} \cap E_{8}) \leq \mathbb{P}(E_{9})
$$

Now

$$
\mathbb{P}(E_{7} \cap E_{8}) = 1-\mathbb{P}((E_{7} \cap E_{8})^{c}) \\
=1- \underbrace{\mathbb{P}\left(E_{7}^{c} \cup E_{8}^{c}\right)}_{N}
$$

\begin{align}
N  &\leq \mathbb{P}(E_{7}^{c}) + \mathbb{P}(E_{8}^{c})\\
&\leq 2 - (\mathbb{P}(E_{7}) + \mathbb{P}(E_{8}))\\
\end{align}

Now
$$
- \mathbb{P}\left(E_{7}^{c} \cup E_{8}^{c}\right) \geq -2 + (\mathbb{P}(E_{7}) + \mathbb{P}(E_{8}))
$$
Adding $1$ both sides,
$$
1 - \mathbb{P}\left(E_{7}^{c} \cup E_{8}^{c}\right) \geq -1 + (\mathbb{P}(E_{7}) + \mathbb{P}(E_{8}))
$$

Now
$$\mathbb{P}(E_{9}) \geq -1 + (\mathbb{P}(E_{7}) + \mathbb{P}(E_{8})
$$

Now
$$ - \mathbb{P}(E_{9}) \leq 1 - \left( (\mathbb{P}(E_{7}) + \mathbb{P}(E_{8}) \right)
$$

Adding $1$ both side,
$$ 1 - \mathbb{P}(E_{9}) \leq \left(1 - \left( (\mathbb{P}(E_{7})\right) + \left(1 - \mathbb{P}(E_{8})\right) \right)
$$

Finally We can write,

\begin{align}
\nonumber \mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i}\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{4}\right) & \leq \cdot \mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E}[f]\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}\right| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \\
& \leq 2 \left|\mathcal{F}\right| \cdot \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon^{2} n d}{9^{4} c L^{2}}\right)+2 \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3}}\right)
\end{align}

**N.B:-**

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i}\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{4}\right) &\leq
\mathbb{P}\left ( \bigcup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \{ \frac{1}{n}\left| \sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i) - \mathbb{E}[f])z_i\right| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\} \right )
&\leq \sum_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \mathbb{P}\left (\frac{1}{n}\left| \sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i) - \mathbb{E}[f])z_i\right| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8} \right ) 
\leq 2 |F| \exp\left (-\frac{\epsilon^2nd}{9^4cL^2} \right)
\end{align}

Answer (score -2):

By contradiction you can exam if right hand sentence happens not, add them together and the left happens not. You can take $\mathbb{E}[f]=\text{sgn}(z_i)$ to minimize the left hand sentences.